# Order of operation in math

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-history

Who decides order of operation in any math calculation.
Is it scientific or arbitrary?
e.g. 1+4-6x7+7

Comment: multiplication originally arises has a shorthand as repeated addition of same quantities. When it comes down to interpret expression like $1 + 2\times 3$,  multiplication naturally should be performed first or there's no point of inventing multiplication as a shorthand.

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: I nearly but didn't downvote your question, as it shares all the typical features as questions with no effort put in, which is one of the explicit requirements for questions on Math SE. This judgement was validated both by the lack of any of your own thoughts or description of research done, as well as the typographical error that would not be there if you had read your question before posting. However, after a brief Google search I did not find any clear explanation of the motivation of order of operations in mathematics, so I gave you the benefit of doubt and tried my best to give an answer.

Comment: So I don't know who downvoted and the exact reason but it's likely to be similar to what I said.

Answer (score 2):

Originally we used numbers to count; 1 apple, 2 apples, 3 apples... Adding was a natural action, and we chose to use "+" to denote addition.

> If we buy 4 apples and 5 oranges, we could represent that as "4 apples + 5 oranges".

Now "4 apples" is the same as "apple + apple + apple + apple", and so we require that:

> "4 apples + 5 oranges" is read as "( 4 apples ) + ( 5 oranges )"
>
> and not for example "4 ( apples + 5 ) oranges" (what on earth would that mean anyway?).

It so happens that we might like to view "4 apples" as "4 times of an apple", and so:

> "$4 \times \text{apple} + 5 \times \text{orange}$" is read as "$( 4 \times \text{apple} ) + ( 5 \times \text{orange} )$".

Now this idea extends to multiples of numbers themselves.

> When we have 2 dozen apples, we have "2 times of a dozen apples" which is "2 times of 12 times of an apple", or in symbols "$2 \times ( 12 \times \text{apple} )$".

Notice that the result of such two-step multiplication is always the same in some sense, namely that it does not matter what was multiplied (in this case an apple). In general $2 \times ( 12 \times \text{X} ) = 24 \times \text{X}$ for any object $X$. So we **define** $2 \times 12$ to be $24$ precisely so that:

> $2 \times ( 12 \times \text{X} ) = ( 2 \times 12 ) \times \text{X}$.

This allows us to manipulate the numbers separate from the objects they are used to count. This also means that it would be most convenient to have the familiar precedence rules (default order of operations). Consider:

> "2 dozen and 3 apples" means "$( ( 2 \times 12 ) + 3 ) \times \text{apple}$.

Clearly by default in our natural language multiplication binds tighter than addition (we interpret "2 dozen and 3" to mean "( 2 dozen ) and 3". Similarly in the symbolic notation it is most convenient to adopt the same convention and so we have:

$2 \times 12 + 3 = ( 2 \times 12 ) + 3$.

Similarly there is usually reasonable justification for each choice of order of operations in general beyond arithmetic, although in some cases different people choose different conventions. For example, in most programming languages "AND" has higher precedence than "OR", but in some logic textbooks they are not allowed to occur consecutively without using brackets to indicate the order.

Comment: Another justification is the great reduction in the need for brackets. Very interesting answer.

Comment: @user254665: Right! We choose the operation precedence precisely to minimize the length of expressions, which often means minimizing the number of brackets. That is why for example we write "$1+2-3+4$" to mean "$((1+2)-3)+4$" and also why we choose "$\neg$" to bind tighter than "$\land$" and "$\lor$".

Comment: @user254665: By the way, if you're familiar with action of a semiring over a module, that is precisely what is happening with counting; we have $\mathbb{N}$ acting on the collection of all real-world objects. In other words the properties of $\mathbb{N}$ fall out from the need for it to act on real-world objects! Same for using $\mathbb{R}$ to measure scalings, which is a field that acts on displacements.